# This program wants jpargmp

Tags: java, pi

I am trying to compile a pidigits program from the language shootout. The java one wants jpargmp. I can not find any information whatsoever on jpargmp. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jpargmp is a native C/C++ library that the program depends on.

If you have a pre-compiled version of the library (called something like `libjpargmp.so` on *nix or `libjpargmp.dll` on Windows) ensure its in a directory which is specified in the `java.library.path` system property. If you don't have a copy of the library, you may have compile it - See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404090/scala-use-of-gmputil-for-pidigits)

Comment: Could you help me compile the files listed in that post? I am using g++ on windows. I just keep getting errors. Every time I correct (to the best of my ability) one, more appear.

Answer (score 0):

There's [a discussion forum for the benchmarks game](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/help.php#reportbugs) ask your question there!